# Обстоятельства и определения

Tags: синтаксис, определения, обстоятельство

1.
На балконе сосед насвистывает какую-то мелодию.
На небе я вижу яркие звезды.

"На балконе" и " на небе" - обстоятельства места, хотя "на небе" явно не смотрится в этом качестве, ибо можно подумать, что говорящий находится на небе. И лучше написать: я вижу на небе яркие звезды.

2.
Опытный фотограф углядел маленькое пятнышко в самом углу снимка.
Прибор зафиксировал неопознанный объект в небе над городом.

Первоисточник утверждает, что здесь обстоятельства места, хотя это скорее обстоятельственные определения, чем просто обстоятельства.
Но они станут обстоятельствами, если их поставить сразу после сказуемого.

Поясните, пожалуйста, эти моменты и скажите, верны ли мои рассуждения.
Может ли обстоятельство все-таки стоять так, как показано во втором пункте? 
Например, при инверсии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В качестве вступления**

Порядок слов в русском предложении ― это вещь в себе. С одной стороны, он вроде бы достаточно свободный, а с другой ― не свободный совсем. Это значит, что порядок слов  может быть  или неправильным (так не говорят), или многозначным, так что при изменении структуры предложения смысл сообщения тоже меняется.

**Эта тема разбирается в грамматике,** в том числе существуют такие понятия, как нормальная и инверсированная позиция слов в сочетаниях, а также различного рода инверсии в предложении, но всё это видится отдельными фрагментами, без общей и хорошо разработанной теории.

**Как же мы тогда говорим?** Обычно носители языка строят предложение интуитивно, особенно не задумываясь над порядком слов. Именно поэтому анализировать надо только **естественную речь,** а не придуманную ради учебного разбора.

1) ***На балконе сосед насвистывает какую-то мелодию. На небе я вижу яркие звезды.***

Оба предложения нужно рассматривать как часть текста, они не должны находиться в неком пространстве. И оба предложения должны иметь **определенную структуру.**

Например: ***Все уже спят, только на нижнем балконе //сосед  насвистывает //какую-то мелодию.*** На балконе ― это детерминант, то есть обстоятельство, отнесенное ко всему предложению. Схема второго предложения такова: детерминант ― предмет/тема (о чем говорится) ― сообщение/рема (что говорится). Это то, что называется **актуальным членением** простого  предложения.

***К вечеру ветер разогнал тучи. Я выглядываю в окно и вижу яркие звезды на небе.***  Обычный порядок слов: вижу (что?), вижу (где?). По-другому не скажешь, и персонаж наш точно не на небе.

***На небе я вижу яркие звезды.***  Как понять предложение, о чем оно? Где здесь тема и рема, есть ли детерминант, какой можно придумать контекст? Ну если только такой: 
― Что ты видишь на небе? ― На небе я вижу луну и яркие звезды. ― Только яркие? ― Нет, не очень яркие тоже вижу.

2) ***Опытный фотограф углядел маленькое пятнышко в самом углу снимка. Прибор зафиксировал неопознанный объект в небе над городом.***

Схемы предложений похожи: углядел что? где?  и зафиксировал что? где?

Только во втором предложении **два неоднородных обстоятельства:** (где?) в небе, (где именно?) над городом. Второе обстоятельство сужает значение первого (уточняющее значение).

**Как различить обстоятельство и обстоятельственное определение (пример)**

***Лестница вела на второй этаж*** (обстоятельство).   ***Лестница на второй этаж была парадной, красиво отделанной*** (обстоятельственное определение). Мы как бы убираем глагол из первого предложения и используем сочетание (предмет + обстоятельство) во втором предложении.

Comment: Хорошо, а если имеем такие предложения. Я зашёл в дом и огляделся. На полу - ковёр, на ковре - горшок. Здесь "на полу", " на ковре" - обстоятельства. А если написать так. Иван, что тебе мешает спать? Голуби на крыше. Здесь голуби (какие?, где?) на крыше. Обстоятельственное определение?

Comment: 1) Эллиптические предложения вида "обстоятельство-подлежащее" (сказуемое пропущено, но оно подразумевается). 2) Неполное предложение: (Мешают) голуби на крыше. Здесь на крыше - обстоятельственное определение (голуби, которые на крыше).

Comment: Вот еще продолжение вашей истории. -Что это за шум? - Да голуби на крыше //дерутся. Здесь "на крыше" - обстоятельство, а порядок слов изменен (инверсирован) в соответствии со структурой тема- рема. Предмет (тема): голуби на крыше, сообщение (рема) : дерутся. Но это актуальное (смысловое) членение высказывания, а грамматика его определяется по прямому порядку слов: Голуби дерутся (где?)на крыше.

Comment: Надеюсь, Вы позволите задать последний вопрос. Я выглянул в окно и увидел мужчину с чемоданом. (с чемоданом - определение). Я видел, как мужчина с чемоданом вошёл в зал. (с чемоданом - определение? Ведь здесь признак по наличию у предмета какой-либо внешней черты, детали.) Девушка в сарафане, с длинными косами вошла в комнату и очаровала всех присутствующих. (в сарафане, с длинными косами - определения; внешний вид). Мужик в тулупе, с топором в руках брел вдоль дороги. (в тулупе, с топором - определения; внешний вид, детали).   Дама с собачкой гуляла по парку. (с собачкой - дополнение? )

Comment: В ваших примерах  использованы несогласованные определения, выраженные падежными формами существительных. Мужчина с чемоданом вошёл в зал,.Здесь форма "с чемоданом" не имеет отношение к действию (сравнить: играть с мячом, игры с мячом), поэтому может быть только определением.

Comment: Прошу прощения, можете, пожалуйста, ответить  на один вопрос. 1) Я представлял себе Вас в том платье из магазина. Может ли здесь "в платье" играть роль дополнения? Представлял (в чем?) в платье. 2) Каждый день я представлял/вспоминал Вас, в красивом платье, с белыми перчатками и великолепной прической. Здесь "в платье...прической" обособ. определение? Смысл в том, что в 1). она не была никогда в том платье, а в 2). он вспоминал внешний вид. 3) Я не могу себе представить Россию без Пушкина. Представлял (что?) Россию, Россию (какую?) без Пушкина? 4) Где она? Лида с собакой гуляет. "С соб." - доп

Comment: В предложениях: 1 - дополнение, 2 - несогласованные определения, 3  - дополнение/определение, 4 - дополнение. Дополнение - предмет, на которое распространяется действие в данном предложении. При обособлении сохраняется грамматическая связь (управление), но слово уже не является членом предложения. В предложении 3 предложную форму можно рассматривать как определительное дополнение/объектное определение в зависимости от смысла: без Пушкина Россия другая, трудно отделить Пушкина от России. В предложении 4 инверсия, но она не меняет роль в предложении (гуляет с собакой).

Answer (score 0):

В чистом виде обстоятельства места, где бы ни стояли.

> ...Ибо можно подумать, что говорящий находится на небе.

Не знаю уж, кто может так подумать.

Answer (score 0):

*Опытный фотограф углядел маленькое пятнышко в самом углу снимка. Прибор зафиксировал неопознанный объект в небе над городом.*

Я думаю, в обоих предложениях под цифрой 2 обстоятельства места являются синкретичными членами предложения.

Фотограф углядел (что?) пятнышко (**где? в чём?**) в углу (чего? каком?) снимка. В углу - обстоятельство места и дополнение.

Фотограф углядел (что?) пятнышко **(где? в чём?)** в углу (чего? каком?) снимка. В углу -обстоятельство места и дополнение.

Обстоятельственного определения я как-то не увидела. Если б было просто "пятнышко в углу", а здесь "в самом углу"- вопрос "какое пятнышко?" как-то не подходит, только где? в чём?

Вот *снимка* - тоже синкретичный член, дополнение со значением несогласованного определения.

*Прибор зафиксировал неопознанный объект в небе над городом.*

Зафиксировал (что?)объект (где? в чём?) в небе (каком? где?) над городом. *В небе* - обстоятельство со значением дополнения. *Над городом* - несогласованное определение со значением обстоятельства.

Инверсия, я думаю, не влияет на синтаксическое значение в данном случае. Вот примеры из учебника для студентов с инверсией: *Опять высматривает, где бы поближе к реке делянку отхватить. (Ф. Абрамов.)*

(Отхватить) делянку(**какую?) поближе к реке** - несогласованное определение; (отхватить **где?) поближе к реке** - обстоятельство места. Синкретичный член предложения - несогласованное определение со значением обстоятельства места. Прямой порядок невозможен.

*На озеро вылазку хочу сделать. (Ф. Абрамов.)*
Вылазку ( какую?) на озеро - несогласованное определение; хочу сделать вылазку (куда?) на озеро.  Прямой порядок: *Хочу сделать вылазку на озеро.* Синтаксическое значение не изменилось: сделать вылазку куда? вылазку какую?

Так что при инверсии и определение, и обстоятельство возможны.